# Fetch only text from png(transparent) image in Javascript Html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I am using `html5` and `javascript`. I want to remove the transparency background from a png image, Which is form of imagedata base 64 code. I want only the text from the transparent image.
Screen Shot:
[image]

**Javascript code:**

```
$contextDialog.find('.fpd-change-text').click(function () {
            console.log("after click");
            thisClass.setElementParameters(currentElement, {text: this.value});
            var a = this.value + 1;
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas22');
            // canvas.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
            canvas.fillText = this.value;
            var text = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.imgTextVarun = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        });
```

**Html Code:**

```
<canvas id="canvas22"></canvas>
```

In the Javascript code I have a text variable containing the base64 code of the image.
I asked a similar question earlier: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587252/canvas-convert-into-transparent-image-but-text-should-not-transparent

I only want the same text from image. Please give me some idea.

Comment: Are you trying to crop the image to the smallest possible size without removing the text? Or, are you trying to get back a text string, "I Love you"? Are you trying to obtain something else?

Comment: @enhzflep I guess he's trying to read the text from image. Something like OCR. Not sure though :)

Comment: yaa Snazzy Sanoj i am trying read the text with style like font size, font style etc.

Comment: @varunsharma - There are lots of OCR (optical character recognition) programs around. Here's one such example: http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html I do note however, that when the image you've posted is given to the demo, that the output is "Remo_e bac_ro_nd
tran_parent _pace." - (I.e, only the [very small] high-contrast text is [poorly] recognised) Tesseract may be a better option. As for getting the font and font-size - that may be a pipe-dream, I don't know. :)